# Concatenating null to string using + results in null

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following SQL Query in Access:

```
SELECT ID, CurrencyName + ' (' + CurrencySymbol + ')' AS [Currency], 
CurrencyLocation, CurrencySymbol FROM Currencies ORDER BY SortOrder
```

What I noticed is that I get a full table of results except if if the field `CurrencySymbol` is left `NULL` or empty. If the `CurrencySymbol` field is null, rather than Concatenate nothing, Access skips over the record and continues as shown below

[image: Snapshot of Access].

Did I get something wrong or is there a better way to write this Query?

Comment: Try using `&` instead of `+` as the concatenation operator. They behave differently when it comes to nulls. You might also want to take a look at the `Format()` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you concatenate strings with `+`, `string + NULL` yields `NULL`.

If you concatenate strings with `&`, `string & NULL` yields `string`.

Thus, you have two options to fix this:

Option 1: `CurrencyName + ' (' + Nz(CurrencySymbol, '') + ')'`. Nz (NullToZero) converts Null values to its second argument.

Option 2: `CurrencyName & ' (' & CurrencySymbol & ')'`

You can use this fact to create an expression that only shows the parenthesis when a currency symbol is present (Credit for this idea goes to [this blog post](http://www.fmsinc.com/free/NewTips/Access/accesstip49.asp)):

`CurrencyName & (' (' + CurrencySymbol + ')')` will yield `Points` and `Euro (€)`.

Comment: Oh I thought Concatenate only works with `+` I didn't know `&` was an option

Comment: `&` is an explicit *string* concatenation operator. So, `3 + 4` yields `7`, but `3 & 4` yields `"34"`.

Answer (score 4):

That's because concatenating a string and NULL results in NULL.

```
SELECT ID, CurrencyName + ' (' + Iif(IsNull(CurrencySymbol), '', CurrencySymbol) + ')'
  AS [Currency], CurrencyLocation, CurrencySymbol
FROM Currencies
ORDER BY SortOrder
```

Comment: With a little modification I get exactly how I was hoping to format it the first time. Thanks!